# How to stop jquery from running in browser and hide Chrome javascript debugger modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to stop jQuery from running in my browser so that I can do some CSS edits to a specific slider.

I know I can use Chrome's developer toolbar to pause the javascript from running but when you pause it, a modal window pops up with the step over button displaying.

I cannot seem to find the source of that modal transparent window because it seems all functionality then stops.

Is there a better way to do this?

I have already deleted all the other sliders to show only one but even then, there is animation movement I don't really want to have happen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While the modal is open you can simply switch to the elements panel in the developer tools, select an element in the dom tree and start editing it, the modal will then disappear while javascript is still being stopped/ paused.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Is there no way of hiding that opaque modal window though?